# Record everything that is typed (in live) in the terminal by modifying the .bashrc file

Tags: command-line, bash

Basically what it should do is each time we type a keystroke, it should go in a text file.

I've tried using "Script" but it records everything (output/input), but it does not record password inputs (sudo).

I've also tried using "Read" and xinput, but it goes into input mode that expects an input.

What I would like to do is, it should record only in the background and write to a file during a terminal session.

Thanks!

Comment: See this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129159/record-every-keystroke-and-store-in-a-file

Comment: If you want all keyboard events, see the link [Record every keystroke and store in a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129159/record-every-keystroke-and-store-in-a-file), as already suggested. There is also **`~/.bash_history`**, that stores the previous commands.

Comment: @sudodus I'm new to bash. I've been trying to do the above solutions, but they are actually recording the keystrokes but they occupy the terminal when I try to use it inside the .bashrc file. I need a solution where in it records and logs all keystrokes to a file in the background while I'm using the terminal. Can you help me with this?

Comment: If you are happy with recording the previous commands, use the command `history`, or after you have closed the bash session or even after reboot,  look at the file `~/.bash_history`, and you will see the commands. Or do you want all the keystrokes? What you see in the terminal is often possible to redirect to a file: instead of `command line` you run `command line > output-file`.

Comment: And if you want to see the output **and** write it to a file, you can use `tee`. So  use the following command syntax, `command line | tee output-file`. If you want to append (write to the end of the file), you can use `command line | tee -a output-file`

Comment: I want to log all keystrokes to a file while someone is using the terminal. The main purpose of this is for us to be able to monitor our machines. So the bash history file wont work for me because it only logs all the executed commands. What i need is to log everything while doing this in the background. Just like the "script" command where it has -quiet option. I'm currently researching about the `command line | output`, but i want to do this automatically without letting the users know. Is that possible? Also, thanks for the suggestions i highly appreciate it!

Comment: I don't think the employees will be happy, if they find out that you are spying on them. Anyway,  there are both hardware and software keyloggers, and you can buy at least some such devices via the internet.